# How can i submit a fom when their is multiple functions are created , which function to call on evnets like onclick and onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, forms

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
        <input type="text" id="txt">
        <input type="text" id="txt1">
        <input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
    var a = document.getElementById("txt");
    var b = document.getElementById("txt1");
    var save =  document.getElementById("btn");

    //save.addEventListener("click" , myFun);
    save.onclick = function(){myFunction()};
    //save.addEventListener("click" , myFunction);

        function myFunction(){

            if((a.value=="") || (b.value=="")){
                alert("fill something");
                return false;
            }else{
            alert("all ok");
            location.href="sec.html";
                return true;
            }

            //a.addEventListener("keyup" , myFun);
            //b.addEventListener("keyup" , myFun);
        }
        a.addEventListener("keyup" , myKeyFun);
        b.addEventListener("keyup" , myKeyFun);

        function myKeyFun()
        {
        if(a.value!==b.value){
                alert("mismatched");
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }   
        } 

    </script>
</html>
```

i have created many function for different - different validation so now i want to submit the form and redirect to another page when all the cinditons are true.
but here form is getting submitted even when the conditions are not true, i have wrote this code just to understand.
the actual code is quite big so i have wrote this to understand how i would have to call the main function to submit the form when there is multilpe function

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess by making different functions. Do it with conditions as below.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("txt");
var b = document.getElementById("txt1");
var save = document.getElementById("btn");
function myFunction() {
  if(a.value == ""){
    alert("Please fill Text 1");
  }else if(b.value == ""){
    alert("Please fill Text 2");
  }else if (a.value != b.value){
    alert("Text 1 and Text 2 must be same");
  }
  else{
    alert("Successfully submitted");
    //redirect to another page code;
  }
}

function textTwoFun(){
  if(a.value != b.value){
    alert('Value missmatched! Text 1 and Text 2 must be same');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Text 1">
   <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="textTwoFun()" placeholder="Text 2">
   <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="click" id="btn">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks but what if i want the value of both field should be equal and if its not equal it will not be submitted and pass the error message and i also want to allow entering only alphabets and i have more then 10 input fileds with different events like keyup , onchange can i do this all in a single function.

Comment: This is not a code writing platform. You should ask separate questions for all of this. Thank you. @ManishPandey

Comment: Yes i know.
i did not see the whole program answered by you before replying to you. i was about to delete but you replied.Thanks once again.

Comment: You can accept and upvote if it is helpful for you. Thanks again.